# How to join any number of tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am having a major problem joining 5 tables because each table only has 1 column in common with only 1 other table.

Here are my tables and columns in each table:

```
TABLE  (COLUMNS)

person  (person_id, first_name, last name)

building  (building_id, building_name)

room  (room_id, room_number, building_id, capacity)

meeting  (meeting_id, room_id, meeting_start, meeting_end)

person_meeting  (person_id, meeting_id)
```

OK, now here is what I am trying to do (pasted from a homework assignment):

> Construct the SQL statement to find all the meetings that person_id #1 has to attend. Display the following columns:
>
> - Person’s first name
> - Person’s last name
> - Building name
> - Room number
> - Meeting start date and time
> - Meeting end date and time

Now I know how to join 2 tables but I have no idea how to pull info from 5 different tables like this.

I tried looking up how to do this and it just says to do a UNION command, and I am just learning and have yet to cover that.

Comment: Post sample data, expected result and query you tried and faced issues with.

Comment: you don't need a union you need a join of the tables. What have you tried so far? Start with two tables and then add another until you have all joined. people aren't going to do the work for you but will assist you on the way.

Comment: I tried going from JOIN to JOIN, one by one, like this:                                    SELECT person.first_name, person.last_name
FROM person
JOIN person_meeting
ON person.person_id = person_meeting.person_id
WHERE person.person_id = 1;                                                                      Then joining the person_meeting table to the meeting table, then the meeting table to the room table and then the room table to the building table....nothing worked.

Comment: Then I tried doing some crazy stuff like this:                                                     SELECT person.first_name, person.last_name,
 building.building_name, room.room_number, meeting.meeting_start, meeting.meeting_end  
FROM person
JOIN person_meeting
ON person.person_id = person_meeting.person_id
AND
FROM person_meeting
JOIN meeting
ON person_meeting.meeting_id = meeting.meeting_id
AND
FROM meeting
JOIN room

Comment: ON meeting.room_id = room.room_id
AND
FROM room
JOIN building
ON room.building_id = building.building_id
WHERE person.person_id = 1;                                                                       But I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Would you add your attempts into the question at the end ("Here is what I have tried") - that will then make a good question. We try not to put code in comments here, because (a) it's not very readable, and (b) comments are temporary and are often deleted by moderators.

Answer (score 0):

As UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set, you don't need it for this scenario. You have to join all the tables one by one based on their Id.

```
SELECT P.First_Name, P.Last_Name, B.Building_name, R.Room_Number, 
M.Meeting_Start, M.Meeting_End FROM Person P 
JOIN Person_Meeting PM ON P.Person_Id = PM.Person_Id
JOIN Meeting M ON PM.Meeting_Id = M.Meeting_Id
JOIN Room R ON M.Room_Id = R.Room_Id
JOIN Building B ON R.Building_Id = B.Building_Id
WHERE P.Person_Id = 1
```

Comment: That's great, so I don't have to use any AND or OR commands or anything!  Thank you so much for your help.